# How do I avoid flash message div from overlapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="/user/update/3" method="POST" class="form-signin">
    <h2> Edit details </h2>

    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>

      <li>Password doesn't match password confirmation.</li>

      <li>messymsg</li>

    </div>



    <input value="lacus. Nulla tincidunt, neque vitae" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" style="cursor: auto; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABHklEQVQ4EaVTO26DQBD1ohQWaS2lg9JybZ+AK7hNwx2oIoVf4UPQ0Lj1FdKktevIpel8AKNUkDcWMxpgSaIEaTVv3sx7uztiTdu2s/98DywOw3Dued4Who/M2aIx5lZV1aEsy0+qiwHELyi+Ytl0PQ69SxAxkWIA4RMRTdNsKE59juMcuZd6xIAFeZ6fGCdJ8kY4y7KAuTRNGd7jyEBXsdOPE3a0QGPsniOnnYMO67LgSQN9T41F2QGrQRRFCwyzoIF2qyBuKKbcOgPXdVeY9rMWgNsjf9ccYesJhk3f5dYT1HX9gR0LLQR30TnjkUEcx2uIuS4RnI+aj6sJR0AM8AaumPaM/rRehyWhXqbFAA9kh3/8/NvHxAYGAsZ/il8IalkCLBfNVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==&quot;); background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    <input value="neque. Nullam ut nisi a" name="title" type="text" class="form-control">
    <input value="turpis.Nulla.aliquet@ornare.edu" name="email" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">
    <input value="" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" style="cursor: auto; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAACIUlEQVQ4EX2TOYhTURSG87IMihDsjGghBhFBmHFDHLWwSqcikk4RRKJgk0KL7C8bMpWpZtIqNkEUl1ZCgs0wOo0SxiLMDApWlgOPrH7/5b2QkYwX7jvn/uc//zl3edZ4PPbNGvF4fC4ajR5VrNvt/mo0Gr1ZPOtfgWw2e9Lv9+chX7cs64CS4Oxg3o9GI7tUKv0Q5o1dAiTfCgQCLwnOkfQOu+oSLyJ2A783HA7vIPLGxX0TgVwud4HKn0nc7Pf7N6vV6oZHkkX8FPG3uMfgXC0Wi2vCg/poUKGGcagQI3k7k8mcp5slcGswGDwpl8tfwGJg3xB6Dvey8vz6oH4C3iXcFYjbwiDeo1KafafkC3NjK7iL5ESFGQEUF7Sg+ifZdDp9GnMF/KGmfBdT2HCwZ7TwtrBPC7rQaav6Iv48rqZwg+F+p8hOMBj0IbxfMdMBrW5pAVGV/ztINByENkU0t5BIJEKRSOQ3Aj+Z57iFs1R5NK3EQS6HQqF1zmQdzpFWq3W42WwOTAf1er1PF2USFlC+qxMvFAr3HcexWX+QX6lUvsKpkTyPSEXJkw6MQ4S38Ljdbi8rmM/nY+CvgNcQqdH6U/xrYK9t244jZv6ByUOSiDdIfgBZ12U6dHEHu9TpdIr8F0OP692CtzaW/a6y3y0Wx5kbFHvGuXzkgf0xhKnPzA4UTyaTB8Ph8AvcHi3fnsrZ7Wore02YViqVOrRXXPhfqP8j6MYlawoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=&quot;); background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    <input value="" name="confirmation" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;); background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!--<input type="hidden" name="role" value="unchecked">-->
    <!--<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="role" checked> isAdmin</label>-->
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <input type="submit" value="Proceed" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="null">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my style.css

```
/* Styles go here */

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
}
.jumbotron h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: gray;
}
.container .footer {
  width: 25%;
}
.form-signin {
  max-width: 30%;
  padding: 19px 29px 29px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #ececec;
  border: 1px solid #9EC03B;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.form-signin h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.form-signin input[type="text"],
.form-signin input[type="password"] {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 7px 9px;
}
.alert {
  position: absolute;
}
```

The form appears something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf0Fl.png

I just want that pink colored alert to not overlap. How do I achieve it?

PS: I created a plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xojui1rIkas7Dr2Slyvz?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set:

```
.alert {
 position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

It's overlapping because of `position:absolute` , So you need to set `position: relative`:

```
.form-signin .alert {
   position: relative;
}
```